# OAuth 2.0 authentication shows 500 Internal Server Error, Spring Boot microservices

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, microservices, role-based-access-control

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 : [no body]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:105) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:170) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:112) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices$1.handleError(RemoteTokenServices.java:69) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:782) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:740) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:583) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices.postForMap(RemoteTokenServices.java:149) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices.loadAuthentication(RemoteTokenServices.java:106) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager.authenticate(OAuth2AuthenticationManager.java:83) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:150) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:348) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:173) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_231]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_231]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_231]
```

I have one auth server and a client server. Logging in on the auth server works fine, returns token. When I take that token and attach it with a secured device, I get the above given error. Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is also possibility, public key which define in your client server not proper(Not authorized client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

401 means that you need to supply credentials to access. If you are using Basic Authentication then you need to add a Authorization request header.

i.e.

```
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + yourAuthToken);
```